# How to properly implement multiprocessing with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am attempting to scale my project to fully utilize my cpu, but I have run into a wall with using keras and multiprocessing properly. My code is attempting to simulate several games in parallel.

```
def create_model(): #Very simple conv-net
    import keras
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Activation
    from keras.models import model_from_json
    from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

    inputs =  Input(shape=(8,8,1))
    X = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform())(inputs)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)
    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform())(X)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output', kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform())(X)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'output': 'binary_crossentropy'})

    return model

def convert(board):
    import numpy as np
    print("converting")


    string_board = str(board)
    data_board = string_board.split()
    final_data = []

    #normalized board values
    variance = 14
    convert = {'.': 0.0, 'p': -1.0, 'r': -2.0, 'n': -3.0, 'b': -4.0, 'q': -5.0, 'k': -6.0,
     'P': 1.0, 'R': 2.0, 'N': 3.0, 'B': 4.0, 'Q': 5.0, 'K': 6.0}
    for char in data_board:
        final_data.append(convert[char])

    final_data = np.asarray(final_data)
    final_data /= variance
    if not board.turn:
        final_data = -final_data
    final_data = final_data.reshape(1, 8, 8, 1)
    return final_data


return_list = []
model = create_model() #This just creates a conv-net



def board_prediction(board): #Get predictions in parallel 
    print("predicting")

    position = convert(board) #Prep board for CNN
    probs, _ = model.predict(position)

    return probs


def log_result(result):
    return_list.append(results)

def apply_async():
    import chess
    from multiprocessing import Manager, Process, Pool

    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(1):
        board = chess.Board()
        pool.apply_async(board_prediction, args=(board, ), callback=log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(return_list)


if __name__ == "__main__": #For future multiprocessing
    #Remove tensorflow intialization message for a cleaner cmd
    import os
    import tensorflow as tf
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})) as sess:
        pass

    apply_async()
```

My code prints my two print lines, but outputs an empty list. Also, scaling the number of times i call the for loop to 3 sucks nearly all the memory from my computer (with 64gb of RAM).

Extra info:
I'm using a single GTX 1080 GPU and a 16-core threadripper CPU

thanks

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal working example? Something like building and training a fake Model with random data and then try to predict in parrallel. It's much easier if we can just copy your code and see what's wrong then. Also this isn't related to your problem but why are you loading your model multiple times?

Comment: will do! Also, loading the model several times was just my desperate attempt at getting it working

Comment: Ok, I editied my post to reflect your comment!

Comment: I can reproduce your error. Unfortunately I didn't get to solve it. Here some thoughts: Why do you open a tf session and close it before calling apply_async? And also why do you want to use multprocessing instead of just using batches?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I want to use multiprocessing because I am attempting to simulate multiple chess games of random length. I don't know how I would implement a batch system considering that property. Moreover, I open that session and pass it before applying the method because it removes that initial debug in tensorflow, in other words, its irrelevant.